# setValuesForKeysWithDictionary on a managedObject gives compilation error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject, kvc

I am trying a core data based app in swift, in which I am performing these steps:

1. Retrieve data from plist
2. Iterate through retrieved data
3. During each iteration insert a managedObject in managedObjectContext
4. Set values in inserted managedObject from dictionary

Below is the code which I am using:

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        // 1. Retrieve data from plist
        var defaultDataPlistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("DefaultData", ofType: "plist")
        var defaultDataArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: defaultDataPlistPath!)

        // 2. Store retrieved data in local db using core data apis
        for menuCategoryDict in defaultDataArray {
            // storing menu categories
            var attributes = menuCategoryDict["attributes"]

            var menuCategory : MenuCategories = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MenuCategories", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as MenuCategories
            menuCategory.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(attributes) // this line is giving compilation error :(
        }

        appDelegate.saveContext()
```

**Problem is** - for some reasons I am getting compilation error: *'AnyObject?' is not identical to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'* at this line:

```
menuCategory.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(attributes)
```

I am clueless, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to retrieve a value from a dictionary it might be that no value exists for the given key. Therefore in swift you do not get a value but a value wrapped in the option type.
The error message basically says that "attributes" is an AnyObject wrapped in an Option and not a value of type AnyObject.
In other words the error message means that you have to check whether the value really exists before using it, because otherwise your app might crash.
The easiest way to unwrap the type would be writing "attributes!" here.
But you should really read about option types because it is a very basic concept in Swift:

[Optional Chaining in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_368)